# c++ Error: expected constructor with declared header file

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I am having an issue on my program file. I have declared "deposit" in my header file but is still expecting something in the program file. Do I need to define amount and What am I missing? Thanks

```
account.cpp:22:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 account::deposit(amount) {
                 ^
```

**Program.cpp**

```
 #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #include "account.h"

//----------------------------------------------------
//Account details
int account::acct( int num, int int_balance){
        acctnum = num;
        bal = int_balance;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Depositing into account
account::deposit(amount) {
    if (amount < 0) {
        std::cout << "The deposit you've enter is negative." 
        << amount << " on account " << acctnum << endl;
    }
    else {
        balance = amount;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Withdrawing from account
//If withdrawel exceeds balance provide error and leave balance
//Else subtract withdrawel from account and update balance
account::withdraw(amount) {
    if (amount < balance) {
        std::cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance." 
        << amount << " on account "<< acctnum << " with balance "
        << balance << endl;
    }
    else if(amount < 0) {
        std::cout <<"The withdrawel you've enter is defined as negative." 
        << amount << " on account "<< acctnum << " with balance "
        << balance << endl;
    }
    else {
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Insert intial balance of account
//If no balance included then give error message and set account balance to 0
int_balance(amount){
    if (amount >= 0) {
        balance = amount;
    }
    else {
        balance = 0;
        std::cout << "Error intial balance invalid" << endl;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
balance(){
    return bal;
}
```

**account.h header**

```
#ifndef account_h_
#define account_h_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class account
{
public:
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account
    int acct(int num, int int_balance);
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    int account_num() const {
        return acctnum;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //constructs bank account with inital_balance
    double balance() const {
        return bal;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //withdrawal from account
    void withdraw(float amount) {
        amount - bal;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //deposit into account
    void deposit(float amount) {
        amount + bal;
    }
private:
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    int acctnum;
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //balance
    double bal;
};

#endif
```

Comment: you need to specify the return type of `account::deposit` when defining it. it should be: `void account::deposit(amount) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Implementation has a type for amount.

```
 void deposit(float amount) {
     amount + bal;
 }
```

It appears you have forgotten it in the .cc file for several methods.  The parameters need a type.

Comment: so I need to redefine it even though I defined it in the header file? @DOUGLAS O. MOEN

Comment: Why is there only an error on deposit even though if this is the case why not give error on withdrawal? @DOUGLAS O. MOEN

Comment: @Bigboy6  No, the implementation file is not considered a definition.  Yes you have to define it (in hh) Yes, you have to implement it, but if the header file does not match the implementation file, the compiler is unable to pair the two items.   Perhaps the compiler quit on the first error?